# IIf the distance from the point $(K, 4)$ to $(2, 4)$ and y axis are same find k.

Tags: coordinate-systems

If the distance from the point $(K, 4)$ to $(2, 4)$  and y axis are same find k.

I can't understand what to calculate. According to my calculation the answer is 1, but the given answer is 0 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is not very clear. You understood the question as "the distance from $(2,4)$ to $(K,4)$ is equal to the distance from $(K,4)$ to the y-axis". But actaully the question is stating that "the distance from $(2,4)$ to the y-axis is equal to the distance from $(2,4)$ to the point $(K,4)$".

I think you know how to work it out now.

$d_{(2,4) \to y-axis}=2=d_{(2,4) \to (K,4)}=\sqrt{(K-2)^2}=|K-2|$

$\implies K-2=2 \implies K=4$

Or

$K-2=-2 \implies K=0$

Comment: It's obvious that we need to change the word "to" on $"and". It's just a typo.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean @Michael, which "to" you want me to change?

Comment: It should be: If the distance from the point (K,4) and (2,4) and y- axis are same

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to change the word "to" on "and". It's just a typo.

If so we have:
$$|K-2|=2$$
Can you end it now?